# ¿Dónde encuentro problemas básicos de programación Java?

Tags: java

Estoy estudiando un curso de programación Java desde 0, sin ningún conocimiento previo. Creo que lo estoy entendiendo bastante bien. He acabado el bloque de los arrays y voy a empezar con las POO pero antes de ponerme duro con ello me gustaría practicar todo lo anterior para tenerlo todo muy claro e ir sobre seguro, al menos todo lo máximo que pueda. ¿Alguien puede decirme o pasarme un PDF o algún enlace donde pueda ver ejercicios básicos resueltos de programación Java? Hasta los arrays solamente.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Tienes cientos de páginas, solo con poner ejercicios java en google te salen unos cuantos. Sirva éste de ejemplo: file:///C:/Users/eltra/AppData/Local/Temp/CUADERNILLO%20DE%20PRACTICAS%20JAVA%20NETBEANS%201_PARCIAL%20CBT.pdf

Comment: @el.trasgu que intentaste hacer ??

Comment: Tal vez intentó poner este enlace: (https://ingfabiandosa.jimdofree.com/app/download/9848911868/CUADERNILLO+DE+PRACTICAS+JAVA+NETBEANS+1_PARCIAL+CBT.pdf?t=1536082696)[https://ingfabiandosa.jimdofree.com/app/download/9848911868/CUADERNILLO+DE+PRACTICAS+JAVA+NETBEANS+1_PARCIAL+CBT.pdf?t=1536082696]

Comment: Huy, pues sí, sí, ese enlace pretendía poner, siento haberlo puesto mal, mil perdones. un saludo

Comment: Muchas gracias por el documento.